# One piece of code hindering my Discord bot for School

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I need this line of code below to check the message the user sends for numbers as a whole, not a specific number ( which is what the 5 is being a placeholder for)

```
  def check(m):
    return m.content == '5' and m.channel == channel
```

help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting whole numbers, use [`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal):

> Return `True` if all characters in the string are decimal characters and there is at least one character, `False` otherwise. **Decimal characters are those that can be used to form numbers in base 10**,

So your code would become:

```py
def check(m):
    return m.content.isdecimal() and m.channel == channel
```

`str.isdecimal()` works like:

```py
>>> '5'.isdecimal()
True
>>> '123'.isdecimal()
True
>>> '0'.isdecimal()  # zero is okay
True
>>> '-123'.isdecimal()  # doesn't work for negative integers
False
>>> '3.76'.isdecimal()  # doesn't work for floats
False
>>> ''.isdecimal()  # doesn't work for empty strings
False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a string contains a number, use the isdigit() method (returns a boolean).

```
string = '1234'
print (string.isdigit())
```